# How to simulate gravity for CCSprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gravity, ccsprite

Currently I am using UIKit in my app but I decided to make the switch to Cocos2D, right now I am trying to implement gravity but I am having trouble doing so. I have googled this and have not found much about it. Anyway is there any way of doing this?

Would anyone like to share what their doing to have a CCSprite have gravity? I really have no idea where I should even begin on how to do this!

Thanks!

Edit1:
I am now using this code:

```
// Create a world
    b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -5.0f);
    bool doSleep = true;
    _world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);
```

For simple y vector gravity. My question is, how would I apply this code to my CCSprite?

Comment: Manually using a float and increasing that by a certain amount

Comment: And the problems you are encountering are?

Comment: @JamesWebster I want to use an actual physics engine, my way of doing it is just not realistic enough. It just doesn't look right.

Comment: Fair enough, "I don't have the knowledge to make this work nicely" is a more than substantial reason to use something other people have written. =]

Comment: true, I will try what the other poster wrote below and I will see how that works out for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking people use physics engines to get this done.  Chipmunk and Box2d are both bundled with cocos2d and can help here, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Ok so if I add, say Box2D since I am only going to do one or the other, how would I implement a BASIC gravity simulation for my CCSprite. Nothing fancy, just something similar to the gravity in most iOS games.

Comment: Have a look at this link:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

Comment: I disagree, if you only need to implement gravity and none of the other features provided by a physics engine like collision detection, etc, a full physics engine would be unnecessary

Comment: @JamesWebster how would you go upon doing it then without a physics engine then? I actually need collision detection anyway but how would I do it without using one? Also little unrelated but for collision detection should I use Chipmunk or Box2D to get the most accurate collisions?

Comment: @MyApps: As per your requirements you described in your last comment I suggest you to use one of the physics engine. Or develop ur own. Again I am waiting for Webster's response over ur last comment so please mention ma name too while adding comment, so that i can get notification :)

Comment: @rptwsthi can I contact you via Skype, I implemented Box2D but I am having issues with the actual gravity part. I followed that tutorial from the other poster but I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

Comment: @MyApps I'm not on skype(I know every one does), But here what u only need to do is, to just drag and drop folder **box2d** (after downloading it from [this Link](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/detail?name=Box2D_v2.2.1.zip&can=2&q=)) on ur project, then import BOX2d.h file, to ur project class, now create `word` and set gravity like: in next comments..

Comment: `b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f);
  bool doSleep = false;
  b2World *world;
  world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);
  
  contactListener1 = new MyContactListener();
  world->SetContactListener(contactListener1);
  
  // Create the container body
  b2BodyDef containerBodyDef;
  //containerBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f,0.0f);
  containerBody = world->CreateBody(&containerBodyDef);
  
  // Create the container box sides by using a polygon assigning each side individually
  b2PolygonShape containerBox;
  int density = 0;`

Comment: `// Bottom edge
        containerBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(-103/PTM_RATIO,50/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(2400/PTM_RATIO, 50/PTM_RATIO));
        containerBody->CreateFixture(&containerBox,density);
containerBody->SetType(b2_staticBody);`

Comment: Looks promising, you should post this as a answer, I'll try it later on when I'm free!